# Using messaging to notify clients of the state of a file being uploaded

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

Is it a good practice to use messaging to notify the client of the state of the current file being uploaded? In my current application, every file which is uploaded goes through a series of checks on the server, for instance EXIF data checks, before notifying the client that this file is completely accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You may hold FileUpload Request on server side till File Acceptance, and use this request reponse to Notify Flex, in FileRefrense Event COMPLETE

Hopes that helps

Comment: I'd be glad if you provide some resource such as an article or a tutorial on this. If it does work for me, it would be much less complicated than throwing messages around